# How to protect parent level styles from user added styles in a description field

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Im using Wordpress but I think this question would apply to any site where users have access to a frontend with posting capabilities.

I want to allow users to style their posts, but only in the description area. 
I don't want the author to have the ability to change the entire page with some clever CSS. I've considered a few ideas but there always seems to be a workaround. I'm stumped, so I've turned off the HTML allow feature for now.

Is their a procedure to protect parent level styles? 
Maybe append an id to every user style with jquery or wrap it with php before thier style executes. ?

Ex. if the user adds:  **.body** or **#description:parent** .. a "wrapped" parent ID would amend or break their style by wrapping it like this:

```
/* #forced_container would be added before their style is applied */

#forced_container.body{ /* user evil invasive style/script */ }
#forced_container #description:parent{ /* user evil invasive style/script */ }
```

or nesting it

```
#forced_container {


 .body{ 
       /* user evil invasive style/script */ 
  }
  #description:parent {
       font-weight: bold;
       text-decoration: none;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Impossible. The client can do what it wants. End of story.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I was hopeful and never hurts to ask ob Stack, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't let the user style anything directly.**

Have an area for custom css that accepts a selector, `key: value;` pairs and nothing else. Then parse that into the css using your own logic. I would have a list of things a selector can't touch, or a whitelist of selectors it can touch.

Below is example pseudo-code. You should not just copy and paste this because it doesn't actually check anything.

```
<head>
    <style>
<?php

    // append custom css in style tag as long as 
    // the selector passes your function's approval
    foreach ( $myCustomCSsInput as $CSS ) {
        if ( isOkaySelector( $CSS['selector'] ) ) {

            // add selector 
            echo "{$CSS['selector']} {";

            // check each `attribute: value;` pair
            foreach ( $CSS['attrs'] as $attr ) {

                if ( isAlsoNotABannedAttribute( $attr['attr'] ) ) {

                    // add the attribute: value; pair
                    echo "{$attr['attr']}: {$attr['value']};";

                } //end if
            }  //end foreach

            // end the selector
            echo "}";
         } //end if
      } //end foreach


function isOkaySelector($value) {
    return true;
}

function isAlsoNotABannedAttribute($value) {
    return true;
}
```

Sample data like below

```
$myCustomCSsInput = array (
        array(
            'selector' => ".OKselector",
            'attrs' => array(
                array(
                    'attr' => "color",
                    'value' => "#BADA55"
                    ),
                array(
                    'attr' => "max-width",
                    'value' => "500px"
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

returns

```
.OKselector {color: #BADA55;max-width: 500px;}
```

Comment: Sounds like from your experience and a few others that it's really just not a good idea to let the users have freedom to access adding styles through a form field like tiny mce, or in my case, the WordPress default editor. As I mentioned to the other guys, I appreciate your experience to help me make a good judgement call, and I'm going to mark this as the answer in the spirit of stackoverflow that you did provided a possible solution and example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have scope like programming languages do, which means a user input style can override site defined styles.  If you're super serious about letting people style some things but not others, you can write a parser that will rename (or strip) styles they create based on what already exists in your theme, but that is a lot more work than it's probably worth.

Comment: Your answer was spot-on, I really appreciate your answer, especially considering my question was more of a open ended proposed solution rather than a technical resolution. I really appreciate your experience.